# In a custom Magento admin module, how can I pass data between my pages?

Tags: php, javascript, magento-1.7, magento

I am experimenting with making a Magento custom admin module and would like pass information between the pages of the module or back to the current page itself for processing.

For example, say I want to connect to my database and add some data to it via AJAX after clicking some button on my admin module page, I would need some standalone script or page somewhere that I could make the request to. Making such a script is not a problem, but how you call it is what confuses me.

Just btw, i'd image if having some standalone script was the right approach for AJAX, the below would be the right was to do it?

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

// do something
```

So in normal PHP I could point the JavaScript Ajax request to somewhere like `/script/dosomething.php`, but in Magento it all works very differently and calling an absolute path of a script seems very bad practice and likely not to work.

So where would I put a script to get called by Ajax and how would I call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your creating a admin module using this method http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers

In your controller you could do

```
class Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();

           //display template.phtml (using update layout.xml)

        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function dosomethingAction(){
         //do database update
         // return a json
    }
}
```

In `template.phtml`

```
<javascript>
  url = '<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('/adminhelloworld/index/dosomething') ?>';

  new Ajax.Request(url, {
     method:'get',
     requestHeaders: {Accept: 'application/json'},
     onSuccess: function(transport) {
         json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();

         if(json.Status.code == 200){
           //do whatever you want with the result
         }
      }
   });
 </javascript>
```